# Schlisel Challah

Tags: minhag, food, challah-shabbat-bread, shabbat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parnassah Segulah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/677/parnassah-segulah)

What is the source of the Minhag to make Schlisal Challah the week after Pesach? Is it better to make a Challah in the shape of a key or is it better to put a key into the dough?

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://mi.yodeya.com/questions/677/parnassah-segulah

Answer (score 0):

For answer see this question
[Schlissel Challah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/677/parnassah-segulah)